Selenium can not be runned by NPM scripts
This is the selenium example I copied from the official page. Only differences are 2 console.log to debug.
const { Builder, Browser, By, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver')
 
;(async function example() {
  console.log(1)
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser(Browser.CHROME).build()
  console.log(2)
  try {
    await driver.get('https://www.google.com/ncr')
    await driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver', Key.RETURN)
    await driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000)
  } finally {
    await driver.quit()
  }
})()

Here is the package.json.
{
  "name": "selenium-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start-js": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "chromedriver": "^131.0.0",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.26.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "^4.1.27",
    "tsx": "^4.19.2"
  }
}


I can run the demo with node index.js and it works. The browser is opened.

However, it doesn't work if I run npm run start-js'. I can not see 2` in the log.

Anyone know why? I searched a lot but didn't find the answer.
Here is my node version v20.12.2 and npm version 10.5.0.
